# How do I increase the distance between the captions of two side-by-side figures?

Tags: floats

Right now I use this:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centerline{
        \begin{subfigure}{0.6\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/mesh12}
        \caption{The acoustic pressure field of a finely meshed 2D model according to equation~\ref{eq:numberofelements} (12 mesh elements per wavelength).}
        \label{fig:mesh1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.6\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/mesh4}
            \caption{The acoustic pressure field of a 2D model with 4 mesh elements per wavelength. }
            \label{fig:mesh2}
        \end{subfigure}
    }
    \caption{Two 2D simulations of the acoustic pressure field with different mesh resolutions. The slit in the middle of the circle is the smartphone and the outer ring is the PML. A single speaker is used. The axes are in meters.}
    \label{fig:mesh4and12}
\end{figure}
```

Which results in a picture like this:
[image]

My problem lies in the fact that the subcaptions of figure (a) and (b) are so close to each other that they look like long sentences. How do I add space between these two captions?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! decrease size of `subfigure`, for example from`0.6\textwidth` (with this figures spill out of text width!) to `0.48\textwidth` and between figures put `\hfill`

Answer (score 3):

Decrease size of `subfigure` environment, for example to `0.47\textwidth`, between figures put `\hfill` and  images sizes determine with `with=\linewidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[font={it,footnotesize}]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centerline{
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.47\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/mesh12}
        \caption{The acoustic pressure field of a finely meshed 2D model according to equation~\ref{eq:numberofelements} (12 mesh elements per wavelength).}
        \label{fig:mesh1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.47\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/mesh4}
            \caption{The acoustic pressure field of a 2D model with 4 mesh elements per wavelength. }
            \label{fig:mesh2}
        \end{subfigure}
    }
    \caption{Two 2D simulations of the acoustic pressure field with different mesh resolutions. The slit in the middle of the circle is the smartphone and the outer ring is the PML. A single speaker is used. The axes are in meters.}
    \label{fig:mesh4and12}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With the `floatrow` package, you can choose the width of the box which contains the (sub)figure and its (sub)caption. Here is an example, for which I chose the natural width of the graphic object:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\DeclareFloatSeparators{qqquad}{\hspace{3em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\floatsetup{subfloatrowsep =qqquad}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/mesh12}}
    {\caption{The acoustic pressure field of a finely meshed 2D model according to equation~\ref{eq:numberofelements} (12 mesh elements per wavelength).}
    \label{fig:mesh1}}
       \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{ \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/mesh4}}
        {\caption{The acoustic pressure field of a 2D model with 4 mesh elements per wavelength. }
        \label{fig:mesh2}}
    \end{subfloatrow}} {\caption{Two 2D simulations of the acoustic pressure field with different mesh resolutions. The slit in the middle of the circle is the smartphone and the outer ring is the PML. A single speaker is used. The axes are in meters.}
\label{fig:mesh4and12}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good man, thanks! There really is a package for everything :)